# ngTable custom refresh action?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, ngtable

I have a table showing data from a remote server. There is a numeric input, when the number is changed I want the table to be refreshed (with the numeric input in arg).

Here is my current attempt:

```
$scope.$watch("number", function () {
    console.log("number changed");
    $scope.user_table_columns.length = 0;
    $scope.user_table_columns = [
        { title: 'Loading... (give it 20-25 seconds)', visible: true}
    ];
    if (typeof $scope.stats != "undefined")
        $scope.stats.length = 0;
    $scope.stats = [];
    //$scope.tableParams.reload();
    $http.get("/api/thing/"+$scope.number).then(function (result) {
        $scope.table_data = result.data;
        $scope.user_table_columns.length = 0;
        Object.keys($scope.stats[0]).forEach(function (col) {
            $scope.user_table_columns.push({ title: col, field: col, visible: true })
        });
    })
});
```

I get `number changed` in my log; but no new HTTP requests.

Comment: loooks ok ..may be it sounds stupid but try some others console.log before and after the if statment..to check if that "if statement" is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Like @cjmling said, try adding some more logs. I also edited the code you posted to use a few best practices:

```
$scope.$watch("number", function (newValue, oldValue) {
  $log.info("number changed");

  $scope.user_table_columns = [
    { title: 'Loading... (give it 20-25 seconds)', visible: true }
  ];

  $scope.stats = [];

  $http.get("/api/thing/" + $scope.number).
  success(function (data, status, headers, config) { 
    $scope.table_data = data;

    var keys = Object.keys($scope.stats[0]);
    angular.forEach(keys, function (col) {
      $scope.user_table_columns.push({ title: col, field: col, visible: true });
    });
  }).
  error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    // An error occured, do something..
    $log.error('HTTP GET failed! Status code: ' + status);
  });    
});
```

There are some utility functions that angular provides for common operations. Here is a list of the angular provided utils: [Angular Functions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function). Another thing to note, you generally want to shy away from `!=` and `==` as those can cause type coercive results when checking conditions. Although `!=` and `==` have a place, it's pretty much always safe to assume you should be using `!==` and `===`. It's also generally a best practice to put quotes around a conditional block, even if it is one line. This just helps people read it more easily. You also shouldn't need to set the `length` property of your `user_table_columns` variable, this updates when you change the array it's referencing.

I added in the usage of the `$log` angular service. It's good practice use this, and it provides some nice utility for logging out information. [$log](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24log).

Finally, I changed your usage of the `$http` service a little bit. It's generally helpful to define the `success` and `error` functions when making a request. Using `.then` works just fine, but it doesn't give you much insight into what happened when the request returned. Guessing that whatever is happening with your request, defining the error handler will probably give you some information. More information is better when trying to debug a problem.

I know this doesn't directly answer your question, but given the information that you posted, it is difficult to do anything more than point you in the right direction for solving your own problem. Since it is logging out `"number changed"`, that makes me guess your AJAX request is failing. Log the output of the success and error callbacks and see what's going on when the request returns. Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Thanks, now using the `$log` service. Actual problem was unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Posted this question at 3AM; turns out the issue was a "typo" of some description…

(assigning a cursor object that I was using to cache to the variable I was caching which was then returned on that route)